# How mavericks/xcode5.0.1 install iOS simulator 5?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

How to install iOS 5.0 Simulator on xCode 5.0.1? It's required to test the application on Deployment Target 5.0. When I update Xcode to 5.0.1 the 5.0 simulator dismiss and no download link in the Preferences-->Downloads

Comment: but i can see the download link in my Xcode for 5.0 simulator..please recheck it.

Comment: mavericks/xcode5.0.1? The oldest version I can get is 6.0.